# Adobe Dreamweaver CC cant open files | welcome.js console is not defined | OSX

Tags: javascript, html, crash, dreamweaver

So... I am trying to open a html file exported from Fireworks (Im Creating a EDM).

I drag the file into Dreamweaver and I get the following dialog:
While executing onLoad in welcome.html, the following Javascript error(s) occurred:

At line 89 of file "/en_US:Configuration:Content:Welcome:HTML5:welcome.js: console is not define".

*Grrr.... ok I will just use open from File menu. Flashes doesnt open. 
*Grr... Ok ill dump the preferences. -No difference
*Grr.... Ok I will Re-Install Dreamweaver 
*Grr..... Ok I will verify HD permissions 
*Grr...... Ok I will just start a file from scratch

As I am referencing images, they dont appear in 'Design' view. Wtf?

**SOLUTION:** Dreamweaver CC can **NOT** have a pipe | in the folder name. Spent WAYYYY too long trying to debug Dreamweaver. Turns out it was a folder name.

Hope this helps others!